# WCF host should provide a single connection to e.g. SAP and hold it open..?

Tags: c#, wcf, sap

I hope this is not a too stupid question but I'm new to WCF.
I have a service with several methods:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISapInter
 {
     [OperationContract]
     FaResults GetMainInfosFromFA(string faNr);

     [OperationContract]
     MatLeadResults GetLeadInfos(string matNr);
 }
```

And every method opens a connection e.g. to SAP:

```
     R3Connection con = new R3Connection("my-connectionstring");
     con.Open(false);
```

and does its job, closes the connetion and sent back the result. ---> Every thing is fine.
But opening such a SAP connection thakes a lot of time.

My question is: Is it possible to open such a connection only once in the wcf host and provide it than in every method call? With other words how or where to instantiate this ´con´ variable that I have access to it?

Comment: Which version of the .NET Connector are you using?

Comment: My question was generelly but I use Theobald-DLL ERPConnect45.